# How to select an array in Cypress?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, automation, frontend, cypress

I´m triyng to select an array, using cypress. I have this element "cy.get(".link.nav-link")[0]"

When I try to click on the element, cypress returned me: "Cannot read property 'click' of undefined"

Below I add my code

```
class Home {
  get services() {
    return cy.get(".link.nav-link")[0];
  }
  
  clickOnServices() {
      this.services.click()
  }
}
export default new Home();
```

Answer (score 4):

`eq` gets A DOM element at a specific index in an array of elements.

Changing `cy.get(".link.nav-link")[0]` to `cy.get(".link.nav-link").eq(0)` should work.

Comment: hey Alapan, it worked very well. Thank you so much.

Comment: Glad to help :)